# Only last radio button control in list being set as checked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a list with each element of the list containing a star rating control which allows the user to set their preference for that element.  The rating control is basically just 5 radio buttons.  The problem I am having is that when I retrieve the preferences the user has previously made, only the last preference is shown, the radio buttons for all elements before that are unchecked.

This is how it looks, showing 4 stars for the last element, however it should also show one for the first and three stars for the second:

[image]

This is the code for the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TaskEntities)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.Forename)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.Surname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AspNetUser.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                var list = new TaskEntityAndPreferencesModel(item, Model.Preferences);
            }
            @Html.Partial("_Rating", list)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CourseID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CourseID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CourseID })*@
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>

    <td colspan="5">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

This is the code for the rating control (_Rating):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model AssignerWebTool.Models.TaskEntityAndPreferencesModel

@{
var checkedOne = false;
var checkedTwo = false;
var checkedThree = false;
var checkedFour = false;
var checkedFive = false;


foreach (var preference in Model.Preferences)
{
    if (preference.UserID == User.Identity.GetUserId() && preference.TaskEntityID == Model.Task.ID)
    {
        if (preference.Rating == 1)
        {
            checkedOne = true;
        }
        else if (preference.Rating == 2)
        {
            checkedTwo = true;
        }
        else if (preference.Rating == 3)
        {
            checkedThree = true;
        }
        else if (preference.Rating == 4)
        {
            checkedFour = true;
        }
        else if (preference.Rating == 5)
        {
            checkedFive = true;
        }
    }
}
}
<div class="ratting-item" data-pid="@Model.Task.ID">
@{
    if (checkedOne)
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" value="1" />
    }
    if (checkedTwo)
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" checked="checked" value="2" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" value="2" />
    }
    if (checkedThree)
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" checked="checked" value="3" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" value="3" />
    }
    if (checkedFour)
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" checked="checked" value="4" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" value="4" />
    }
    if (checkedFive)
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" checked="checked" value="5" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input class="rating" name="vote" type="radio" value="5" />
    }
}

</div>
<span class="result"></span>
```

Im not sure why this is only working for the last element and not any previous, so any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Models:

```
public class TaskEntityAndPreferencesModel
{

    public TaskEntity Task { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserTaskEntityPreference> Preferences { get; set; }

    public TaskEntityAndPreferencesModel(TaskEntity task, IEnumerable<UserTaskEntityPreference> preferences)
    {
        Task = task;
        Preferences = preferences;
    }
}


public partial class TaskEntity
{
    public TaskEntity()
    {
        this.UserAssignedToTaskEntities = new HashSet<UserAssignedToTaskEntity>();
        this.UsersUserPreferences = new HashSet<UsersUserPreference>();
        this.UserTaskEntityPreferences = new HashSet<UserTaskEntityPreference>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string RelatedSubjects { get; set; }
    public int MaxNumberOfUsers { get; set; }
    public int TaskGroupID { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Task_Group Task_Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAssignedToTaskEntity> UserAssignedToTaskEntities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersUserPreference> UsersUserPreferences { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserTaskEntityPreference> UserTaskEntityPreferences { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}


public partial class UserTaskEntityPreference
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public int TaskEntityID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual TaskEntity TaskEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The whole purpose of radio buttons is that you can only select one for the group (and all you radio buttons belong to one group named `vote`).

Comment: In any case all this code is completely unnecessary. All you need to a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` - e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Preferences.Count; i++) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Preferences[i].Vote, 1) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Preferences[i].Vote, 1) // plus other 3 }` and this will all be done automatically

Comment: Ah I see, that makes good sense, you've been a great help to me.

Comment: I just gave an example, but you need to show your models if you want an answer showing the actual code you need to use (which will be about 1/10 of the code your currently using)

Comment: Models added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that only the last radio button is selected is because all your radio buttons have the same `name` (group) and you can only select one radio button from a group.

In the 1st iteration of your loop, the radio button with `value="1"` is selected for that `Preference`. In the 2nd iteration, the radio button with `value="3"` is selected, but because only one radio button can be selected, the `checked` attribute is removed from the previous one. The process continues for each iteration and only the radio button matching the last `Preference` is selected.

To solve this, you need to give each 'grouping' a different `name` attribute, so that the 5 radio buttons for the 1st `Preference` will have (say) `name="vote1"` and the 2nd (say) `name="vote2"` etc.

However, none of your javascript is necessary if your just generate the view correctly in the first place by binding to your model, and in your case you should be using a [view model][1] (I would hate to see the scripts you must be using to convert it all back to to your model when you post the values).